# Memory Not Releasing after Shutting down Tomcat on Linux Machine

Tags: performance, ubuntu, memory-management, jvm, tomcat7

I have an issue, i am running my web app on Linux machine using tomcat.

Issue is When i start my application :
1. It allocates 2 GB real memory
2. I execute data of 5 Million or something, it again increases to 2.5 GB 
3. Issue arrives after shutting the Tomcat down, the Memory is not released at all.

System Details : 32 GB RAM, Ubuntu, JAVA 7
Software : DB = Oracle, Tomcat 7

thnks

Comment: Is it because of JVM, Tomcat or OS

Comment: How do you know the memory not released? please paste more info.

Answer (score 1):

First, please check if the process was killed when you shut down the Tomcat server. For example: `ps -ef|grep tomcat`.

Comment: to stop tomcat we have to use "stop" only or "shutdown"?

Comment: Normally, the "shotdown" script would work if you set up correctly. But in case of memory leak, you'd better use "kill -9 $PID" since the "shotdown" script may not work.